# In my Flutter project, I get the error "Could not resolve all files for configuration"

Tags: android, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am getting the error I attached in my flutter project. When I try to run my project on the Android emulator, it gives this error. I updated all my existing flutter, dart and packages and made changes to the .Build.gradle file, but it didn't work. If anyone has any ideas about the error, I would be very happy if they could help.[image]

I made the necessary package and flutter and dart updates and the packages in the firebase section are up to date. I have no other idea what is causing my problem.

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':cloud_firestore:parseDebugLocalResources'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':cloud_firestore:androidApis'.
   > Failed to transform android.jar to match attributes {artifactType=android-platform-attr, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for PlatformAttrTransform: /Users/hd/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-33/android.jar.
         > /Users/hd/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-33/android.jar

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please [don't show pictures of text and code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code#dont-use-screenshots-of-text). Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search. You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.